# Radio button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code I wanted to create a question with 3 possible answers. The user clicks on one of them. then the question disappears. My problem is that the question disappears on load, before the user clicks on it.
PS: I'm new to programming and JavaScript so please try to dumb down your answers.

Thank you in advance. :)

```js
$("input:radio").attr("checked", false);

function disappear(a) {
  $("#q" + a).fadeOut(1500);
}

$(".choice1").click(disappear(1));
```

```html
<form id="q1">
  58*2=
  <br>
  <input type="radio" class="choice1" name="a1" value="1" />128
  <input type="radio" class="choice1" id="r1" name="a1" value="2" />116
  <input type="radio" class="choice1" name="a1" value="3" />126
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your click handler.

```
$(".choice1").click(disappear(1));
```

The above calls the function `disappear` on load as you are not passing a reference of the function as a callback.

Write a valid anonymous callback for the handler

```
$(".choice1").click(function(){
    disappear(1)
});
```

As a side note you can pass a function reference in a handler like below, considering it is parameterless. Else you would need a anonymous func wrap as explained above.

```
    $(".choice1").click(disappear);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an event handler, you are actually triggering click event.

```
$(".choice1").click(disappear(1));
```

triggers the click event, doesn't bind it to the class.

this is how you bind click to a class: -

```
$("input:radio").attr("checked", false);

function disappear(a) {
  $("#q" + a).fadeOut(1500);
}

$(".choice1").click(function(){
    disappear(1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the 'change' event instead as it will fire only when the radio button is changed

```js
$("input:radio").attr("checked", false);

function disappear(a) {
  $("#q" + a).fadeOut(1500);
}

$(".choice1").on('change', function(){
  disappear(1);
});
```

```html
<form id="q1">
  58*2=
  <br>
  <input type="radio" class="choice1" name="a1" value="1" />128
  <input type="radio" class="choice1" id="r1" name="a1" value="2" />116
  <input type="radio" class="choice1" name="a1" value="3" />126
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, since there will be many questions, you could do

```
$("input:radio").attr("checked", false)
                .click(function(){$(this).parent('form').fadeOut(1500);})
```

Write less, do more ..., see here: http://jsfiddle.net/wm9gdr2n/1/

The click-function will *find* the relevant `<form>` that needs to be faded  by using `parent()`. In case your checkboxes are packed into some `<div>` within the `<form>` you will have to use `parents()` instead, since `parent()`will only find the *direct* parent (which would then be the `<div>`).

This way you *won't* have to write

```
$(".choice1").click(function(){disappear(1)});
$(".choice2").click(function(){disappear(2)});
$(".choice3").click(function(){disappear(3)});
...
```

for each question. And `disappear(a)` is obsolete.

(You might have to include some more detail to the selector if there are checkboxes on your page where you *don't* want this mechanism to happen.)

Answer (score 1):

You have fired the click event rather than defining a callback. A possible way for your need could be:

```js
$("input:radio").attr("checked", false);

$(".choice1").click(function() {
   var me = $(this), index = me.attr('name').substring(1); 
   $('#q' + index).fadeOut(1500);
   
});
```

```html
<form id="q1">
  58*2=
  <br />
  <input type="radio" class="choice1" name="a1" value="1" />128
  <input type="radio" class="choice1" id="r1" name="a1" value="2" />116
  <input type="radio" class="choice1" name="a1" value="3" />126
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The main change in the above code was to read the index from the "name" of the radio boxes. This is to avoid passing the index like "1" from the arguments.